# android flat button

Tags: android, button

i have buttons with rounded corners, how to make them looks like this : [image]

do i need to define my own style? I don't want to change my code, only XML resources, if it possible how to apply this(border radius = 0) style to my buttons?

Comment: define your own custom style or use images as background...

Comment: show your xml code for button creation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://android-holo-colors.com/

This service generate Holo-styles for checked components(button is your case) and then you can download zip with xml's.

Use it to fast&easy implement, or code samples.

Answer (score 6):

I think the only way for you to get what you want it to write XML to make it possible.

In the drawable folder, create an xml file that will represent the shape of your button.

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#ff00ff" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#20f8f6" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" /> // set to 0 or erase it for sharp corners
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#ff00ff"
          android:endColor="#992f2f"
          android:angle="270" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#992f2f" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

then you need to create a style in your styles.xml file

```
<resources>
  <style name="button_text" >
    <item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity" >center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin" >3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize" >30dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor" >#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx" >1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy" >1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius" >2</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and when you declare your button in the xml

```
 <Button
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Styled Button"
        style="@style/button_text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this github post [here](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button).

Mainly check out the library provided there and added to that source code.

**SnapShot:**

[image: Flat Button]

Answer (score 2):

add xml(example.xml) in folder drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
                android:topRightRadius="4dip"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="4dip"/>
            <solid android:color="#1FC1BA"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
                android:topRightRadius="4dip"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="4dip"/>
            <solid android:color="#26262C"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
                android:topRightRadius="4dip"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="4dip"/>
            <solid android:color="#1B978F"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

on your folder layout(activity_main.xml) in the button

- android:background="@drawable/example"

  ```
      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="exampleText"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/example"
          android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think below code is exactly what you are looking for.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#32a5cf"
          android:endColor="#32a5cf"
          android:angle="270" />
      <stroke
          android:width="7dp"
          android:color="#9032a5cf"
           />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```